# Pros and cons of organizing variables and methods in namespaces

Tags: c++, namespaces

I have some variables and methods which need to be easily accessible from everywhere, while keeping them well organized. I used to keep them in classes organized by "category" and pass references to these classes to functions/methods (through parameters) which needed them.

Then I realised that was too messy, ugly and hard to make changes, so I got rid of the references through parameters and declared them globally.

Then I realised most of these classes had only one instance and made ALL the methods and member variables static, and removed the only instance each of these classes had.

Then I read something on the internet and realised (yes, again) that it would be even better to use namespaces instead of classes (I can use `using namespace`, which is very handy). Right now it's kinda like this:

```
// header
namespace Graphics
{
    // some functions
    void Initialize(HWND hWnd);
    void CreateTextureRenderTarget(UINT Width, UINT Height, DXGI_FORMAT Format, ID3D11RenderTargetView** RenterTargetOutput, ID3D11ShaderResourceView** ShaderResourceOutput, bool GenerateMips = false);
    // ...
    extern CComPtr<IDXGIFactory> Factory;
    extern CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> Adapter;
    extern CComPtr<IDXGIOutput> Output; // The output (display monitor)
    extern CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> SwapChain;
    extern CComPtr<ID3D11Device> Device;
    extern CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> ImmediateContext;
    // ...
}

// source
namespace Graphics
{
    CComPtr<IDXGIFactory> Factory;
    CComPtr<IDXGIAdapter> Adapter;
    CComPtr<IDXGIOutput> Output;
    CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> SwapChain;
    CComPtr<ID3D11Device> Device;
    CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> ImmediateContext;
    // ...

    void Initialize(HWND hWnd)
    {
    // ...
```

And now I'm wondering: what are the pros and cons about using namespaces like I am?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have two namespace:

```
namespace one {
print(){ cout<<"one"<<endl;
}
namespace two {
print(){ cout<<"two"<<endl;
}
```

In main file:

```
using namespace one;
using namespace two;

int main(){
   print(); // conflict arises because it doesn't know which print to call
}
```

Output:

```
Error: Call of overloaded print() is ambiguous.
```

To resolve this problem we use scope resolution operator(::).

In main file:

```
int main(){
   one::print();
   two::print();
}
```

Output:

```
one
two
```